# Can a Facebook App for remote login be identified with IP instead of domain name?

Tags: authentication, facebook

I have a list of sites running on the same server, so they all share the same IP address. a facebook app was created in order to have login functionality on the sites, but as I see, the app needs one and only domain (for security reasons...) that is enabled to use the login process.

Is there a way to identify remote sites with IP instead of one domain name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you must use a domain name, you can enter multiple domain names though, or run the logins through login.yoursites.com or something like that